# What is the least possible value of $|\mathcal{C}|$ if $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies some conditions...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of subsets of $A=\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ satisfying the following two conditions:
>
> 1. Every $9$ element subset of $A$ is in $\mathcal{C}.$
> 2. For any non empty subset $C\in\mathcal{C}$ there is $c\in C$ such that $C\setminus\{c\}\in  \mathcal{C}.$
>
> What is the least possible value of $|\mathcal{C}|$?

I can find a family $\mathcal{C}$ with $10+5+5+3+3+2+2+2+2+1=35$ members:

Clearly there are $10$ 9-element subsets, now we delete some elements in a sucsession and get:

- 8-element subsets: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\color{red}8\}$, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,9,\color{red}{10}\}$, $\{1,2,3,\color{blue}4,7,8,9,10\}$, $\{1,2,5,\color{blue}6,7,8,9,10\}$, $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.
- 7-element subsets: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\color{red}{7}\}$, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\color{red}9\}$, $\{1,2,\color{blue}3,7,8,9,10\}$, $\{1,2,\color{blue}5,7,8,9,10\}$, $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,\color{green}9\}$.
- 6-element subsets: $\{\color{red}1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\{1,2,7,8,9,\color{blue}{10}\}$, $\{3,4,5,6,7,\color{red}8\}$.
- 5-element subsets: $\{\color{red}2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\{1,2,7,8,\color{blue}9\}$, $\{3,4,5,6,\color{red}7\}$.
- 4-element subsets: $\{3,4,5,6\}$, $\{1,2,7,8\}$
- 3-element subsets: $\{3,4,5\}$, $\{1,2,7\}$
- 2-element subsets: $\{3,4\}$, $\{1,2\}$
- 1-element subsets: $\{3\}$, $\{1\}$ and empty set $\{\}$

But, can it be done better?

Comment: Alternatively, consider $A\setminus C$ instead of $C$. Then: 1. Every $1$ element subset of $A$ is in $\mathcal C$, 2. For every $C\ne A, C\in \mathcal C$, there is $c\not\in C$ s.t. $C\cup\{c\}\in C$. Then at first try, I also get $35$: First $10$ one-element sets $\{i\}$, $5$ pairs $\{2i-1,2i\}$, $\dots$

Comment: If $A$ has $n$ elements, then the least possible value of $|\mathcal{C}_n|$ is $1, 3, 6, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 30, 35, \dots$ which is [A123753](https://oeis.org/A123753) (partial sums of the length of binary representation of $2n+1$). I calculated this using integer linear programming.

Comment: Alternatively, $|\mathcal{C}_n|=1+a(n+1)$ where $a(1)=0$, $$a(n) = n + \min \{ a(k)+a(n-k) : 1 \le k \le n-1 \}$$ according to the OEIS comment. (Here, $a(n)$ is the *binary entropy function*.)